# Why is the output different than expected in this code?

Tags: c, struct, union

Im studying C structs and union and i came across this code. As far as i would know, union works like objects, therefore, printf should be the same as 
a,b,c,d

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Type {
    char A[2];
    struct{
        char B;
        char C;
    };
};

int main(){

    Type Data;
    Data.A[0] = 'a';
    Data.A[1] = 'b';
    Data.B = 'c';
    Data.C = 'd';

        printf("%c %c %c %c \n", Data.A[0], Data.A[1], Data.B, Data.C);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output not actually a, b, c, d?

Comment: They hold the highest byte element, though, i can't see how their shared memory is overwritten by a struct

Comment: @JohnJones Only one member of your `union` can be active at any time, e.g., in `union { char a; int b; } t;`, either `t.a` is valid or `t.b`, but never both at the same time. It's the same with your union, either `A` is valid or `B` and `C` are valid. `B` and `C` both belong to the anonymous struct member of your union, which is why both can be valid at the same time, it's just syntactic sugar. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union

Comment: So, inside my union my nested struct has equivalency of my char, but implicitly its the last element active?

Comment: @JohnJones What do you mean by `has equivalency`? And yes, as soon as you do `Data.B = 'c'`, the anonymous structure becomes the active element and you accessing `A` becomes undefined behavior in most cases.

Comment: if i had union type{ int a, int b, int c, int d, struct { char B, char C}}, the result would be the same, right?

Comment: @JohnJones Yes, the anonymous structure would be at the same level as `a`, `b`, ..., thus only one of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` or the anonymous structure could be active at any time.

Comment: ah i see, i didnt know that detail, thanks a lot for your time! its much clearer to me now

Comment: After `union Type { /*...*/ };`, in C, there is no type named `Type`. Are you perhaps using a C++ compiler; or a non-standard C compiler? If you want to avoid mistakenly using a C++ compiler, add these 3 lines at the top if your code: `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error wrong compiler` / `#endif`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   This is because the statement: `Type Data;` is not correct.  It should be: `union Type Data;`   Your compiler should have told you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Union type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type)

> In `C` and `C++`, untagged unions are expressed nearly exactly like
>   structures (structs), `except that each data member begins at the same
>   location in memory`.

And size of unions is the size of largest element of union. In your case

```
union Type {
    char A[2];
    struct{
        char B;
        char C;
    };
};
```

total of `two bytes` gets allocated for whole union and *all members starts accessing data from the same base starting address of union*.

When these two statement

```
Data.A[0] = 'a';
Data.A[1] = 'b';
```

it looks like

```
      A[0]                  A[1]
 -------------------------------------------
|      'a'         |        'b'            |
 -------------------------------------------
       B                    C   
0x100              0x101
  |
 lets assume 0x100 as base address of union
```

and if you access `Data.A[0]` and `Data.B`, both gets prints as `a` as both `Data.A[0]` and `Data.B` starts accessing data from starting address i.e `0x100`. Also `Data.A[1]` and `Data.C` will prints same as both accessing data from `0x101` memory location.

When below these two statements

```
Data.B = 'c';
Data.C = 'd';
```

executes, it looks like

```
               A[0]                       A[1]
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
|      'c' (overwritten 'a')  |    'd'(overwritten 'b')            |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
               B                              C   
0x100                         0x101
  |
 lets assume 0x100 as base address of union
```

Now if if you prints both `Data.A[0]` and `Data.B`, it prints the data at `0x100` memory location and that is `c` as earlier data gets overwritten. Similarly both `Data.A[1]` and `Data.C` prints `d`.